# C++: Switching from MSVC to G++: Global Variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, g++, visual-c++

I recently switched to Linux and wanted to compile my Visual Studio 2010 C++ source code, which uses only the STL, on G++.

My Linux machine currently isn't available but I can try to tell you what is going on, first:

- As I try to compile my project, all global variables I use in `main` and which perfectly work on MSVC result in `myGlobalVar is not defined in this scope` errors.

My project is built nearly the same as the example below:

```
// myclass.h
class myClass
{
 // ....
};
extern myClass globalInstance;

// myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
// myClass functions located here
myClass globalInstance;

// main.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
int main( )
{
    // Accessing globalInstance results in an error: Not defined in this scope
}
```

- What am I doing wrong?
- Where are the differences between G++ and MSVC in terms of global variables?

Comment: Do you get the same error for static members of myClass?  Also, are you using any namespaces?

Comment: @andand: I didn't try out if the error occurs with static members but I suppose not, they don't have anything to do with my globals problem at all. I can create new instances of myClass in main just fine. Namespaces? No. And even if I did, as far as I know they behave the same in MSVC and G++ - Why should that be a problem?

Comment: that code will work. So thats not the problem. Post some code that doesnt work

Comment: Try compiling main.cpp with -E so that it just spits out the preprocessed code. Look at that and see if there any clues i.e. is everything you expect to be there actually there?

Comment: Try explicitly specifying the global namespace, ie. ::globalInstance. Any difference?

Comment: Your code works for me under GCC 4.2.1. To test, I added an instance variable, `x`, to `myClass`. Then in `main.cpp` I did: `globalInstance.x = 42; cout << globalInstance.x;`. It compiled, and it ran.

Comment: It is hard for me to post the whole 5.000 lines part of my project that doesn't work, but I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to compile as follow:

g++ main.cpp myclass.cpp -o myapp

NOT as follow:
g++ main.cpp -o myapp which will miss global variable declaration in myclass.cpp file.

Comment: Huh? I thought the global variable declarations were in myclass.h, not myclass.cpp. The file myclass.cpp is irrelevant surely? Why would it appear on the compile line at all?

Comment: If that were Troubadour's problem, the error would come from the linker about a missing symbol, not from the compiler about an undefined variable.

Comment: @Dennis: I think you  mean "feed the fire" instead of me? I agree that this answer fixes a linking error and not the compilation error that the OP posted ("...in this scope").

Comment: @feed the fire: Note that it would probably be more standard to add myclass.o to the build line for main.cpp rather than myclass.cpp. The object file myclass.o would be built from a separate compile line such as `g++ -c myclass.cpp`. Doing it the way @myona suggests means there is no intermediate object file and as your project grows bigger you will be hit with longer and longer compilation times. As @Noah suggests familiarise yourself with `make`, or a wrapper for it, so that you only need to rebuild the things that have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code should work just fine on Linux as well as Windows. There shouldn't be any differences between GCC & MSVC with regards to visibility of global variables. I think it's more likely that what you're seeing is a symptom of another problem.

The only thing I can think off off the top of my head that might cause an issue like this would be "screwed up" header files, to use the technical term for it. A common issue in porting code from Windows to Linux is header file case sensitivity. Whereas MSVC won't care if you import MyHeader.h as `#include <myheader.h>` it will certainly fail on Linux. If you header isn't being included, the compiler would miss the extern declaration and might result in the error you're seeing.

Comment: Based on the comments above, it's probably not the specific header file issue I was thinking of.